# Custom script action in Azure Data Factory HDInsight Cluster

Tags: azure, apache-spark, azure-hdinsight, azure-data-factory

Is there a way to run custom script action (or install python packages) when creating on demand HDInsight cluster in the Azure Data Factory v2?

In Azure Data Factory documentation custom script actions are not listed as available parameters.